# Wiremock Request Templating for JSON Payload with multiple allowed keys, but same response

Tags: wiremock, wiremock-standalone

Trying to mock an API endpoint that allows a request with 2 possible payloads, but the same response:

### Request Option 1

```
{
  "key1": "value1"
}
```

### Request Option 2

```
{
  "key2": "value2"
}
```

Based on the [Request Templating documentation](http://wiremock.org/docs/request-matching/), I see that there's an option to define some regex for `matchesJsonPath`.
However, I'm unable to figure out how to provide a configuration that will allow `key1` or `key2`.

This is what I'd tried, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
{
  // ... other configs
  "request": {
    "bodyPatterns": [
      {
        "matchesJsonPath": "$.(key1|key2)"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Is it possible to provide 1 definition that supports both payloads, or do I have to create 2 stubs?

*Note: I am using a [standalone Wiremock Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/rodolpheche/wiremock/), so options for more complex handling using Java are limited.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JsonPath matcher is formatted incorrectly. You need to apply a filter/script (denoted by `?()`). More information about how JsonPath matchers work [can be found here.](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/)

Here is what the properly formatted JsonPath matcher could look like:

```
{
  "matchesJsonPath": "$[?(@.key1 || @.key2)]"
}
```

If you need the `key1` and `key2` to have specific values, that would look like:

```
{
  "matchesJsonPath": "$[?(@.key1 == 'value1' || @.key2 == 'value2')]"
}
```